# jQuery Mobile and Knockout.js Issues

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Ive read alot about jQuery Mobile and Knockout.js not playing nice together.  Should I ditch knockout.js for my mobile pages and stick with jquery mobiles javascript to handle my view updates?  Is there a better option?

Comment: I've got them working together just fine.  The key is using some KO custom-bindings which force JQM to refresh the pages after KO has done it's stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They work fine together. You will need to manually invoke jquery mobile's various widget methods if you are dynamically generating markup with ko's templating or if you are manipulating CSS or other properties. Custom bindings are another valid approach.

```
$('#myButon').button('refresh');
$('#myListview').listview('refresh');
$("#myCheckboxList").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

If your markup is static other than text values, it should be no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

I just started a new project for mobile website, JQM and KO are combined, they are great frameworks and I've never seen any big issue with them.